# Как обьединить мощность нескольких машин под управлением одной ОС

Tags: linux, администрирование, кластеризация, кластер

В общем есть три машины стандартные 64х , как бы из обтединить в одну ииустановить на все это одну ось линукс

Comment: что в Вашем понимании есть объединение мощности?

Comment: В идеале несколько удаленных машин пользователи которые управляют одной и той же системой как разные пользователи обычной системы линукс которая стоит натобычном компе

Comment: Понятнее не стало

Comment: Ты уже задавал подобный вопрос в прошлом году. Ответы были не подходящие?

Comment: да задавала но тут чуть другие условия и много времени прошло может что появилось лучше